# PHP Regex Search and Replace img 'src' Attribute to 'data-src'

Tags: php, html, regex, expression

I want a regex code, to replace all "src" strings to "data-src" for img tag only.

here is an example:

```
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>

<p><img src="http://www.domain.com/images/test.jpg"></p>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>

<p><iframe src="https://www.test.com/embed/4PJWKNOQIf4?list=PLMf7VY8La5RFDHl_LirAIRK1fhxBWIhqx" frameborder="0" width="300" height="169"></iframe></p>
```

shoud be:

```
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>

<p><img data-src="http://www.domain.com/images/test.jpg"></p>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>

<p><iframe src="https://www.test.com/embed/4PJWKNOQIf4?list=PLMf7VY8La5RFDHl_LirAIRK1fhxBWIhqx" frameborder="0" width="300" height="169"></iframe></p>
```

so, that's means all "src" attribute just in img tag should be replaced by "data-src".

i tried to use this regex pattern but its not working.

I'm sorry for my english.

Thank you.

Comment: Where have you gotten stuck trying to solve this problem yourself?

Comment: If you replace `src` with `data-src` your images will no longer be visible. You should *never* parse HTML with regex. Use [a PHP DOM parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) instead.

Comment: I agree with Jay Blanchard, you shouldn't parse HTML by regex but instead use a real parser -- but -- you've missed to show which regex you were trying?

Answer (score 1):

Use a DOM Parser.. But if you want to do it with regex, you can use the following to match:

```
(<img\s*?)src
```

And replace with:

```
$1data-src
```

If you are using other attributes before `src` you can use the following instead:

```
(<img.*?)src
```

See [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/tA9dT2/3)